# The state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

First of all,  I have researched this question but I still can't figure out why it isn't working for me.

I'm developing a Dynamic Web application in Java that uses JPA to store login information of the users. I have no trouble inserting new users or listing all users from the table. But I'm trying to write a login method to authenticate users, in which I only want to select the user with the given username and password.

Here's the method in my `DaoImpl` class:

```
public User login(String userName, String passWord) {
    String sqlCommand = String.format("select u from users u where u.uname = '%s' and u.password = '%s'", userName, passWord);
    Query q = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(sqlCommand);
    //q.setParameter("uname", userName);
    //q.setParameter("pass", passWord);

    try{
        return (User) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here's the entity class:

```
@Entity(name=User.TABLE_NAME)
@Table(name=User.TABLE_NAME, schema=PersistentObject.SCHEMA)
public class User extends PersistentObject{

public static final String TABLE_NAME ="users";

public static final String FIRST_NAME ="fname";
public static final String LAST_NAME = "lname";
public static final String USERNAME ="uname";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

@Column(name=FIRST_NAME, nullable=false)
private String firstName;

@Column(name=LAST_NAME, nullable=false)
private String lastName;

@Column(name=USERNAME, nullable=false, unique=true)
private String userName;

@Column(name=EMAIL, nullable=false, unique=true)
private String email;

@Column(name=PASSWORD, nullable=false)
private String passWord;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<Update> updateList;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user1")
private List<Friend> friendList;

public User() {
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String userName,
        String email, String passWord) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.email = email;
    this.passWord = passWord;
}
```

And in my Servlet, I'm trying to call the `login()` method of my `DaoImpl` class like this:

```
User loggedInuser = this.userDao.login(request.getParameter("uname"),   request.getParameter("pass"));
```

And this is the error I get at the same line:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: <|Exception Description: Problem compiling [select u from users u where u.uname = 'something' and u.password = '12345']. |[28, 35] The state field path 'u.uname' cannot be resolved to a valid type.|[57, 67] The state field path 'u.password' cannot be resolved to a valid type.`

The weird thing is that I don't get this error if I try to filter for the id or the email columns. The login is successful then. But for every other column, I get the above error.

Comment: You should NEVER insert query parameters with String.format(). This is prone to errors and SQL injection. Use Query.setParameter().

Comment: I wasn't planning on using String.format(), as I had already commented. It was just another way to try and see what I could have messed up. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The query you're executing is not a SQL query. It's a JPQL query. JPQL is a different language. In particular, it never uses table and column names. It always uses entity names and their mapped fields/properties names.

So the query should be

```
select u from User u where u.userName = :name and u.passWord = :password
```

Note that in addition to injection attacks due to the usage of `String.format()` instead of named parameters, your query also won't work as soon as the user name or password contains a singla quote. Storing passwords in clear-text in the database is also not a good idea at all. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: My problem was indeed that I was referencing column names instead of the field name.
As for your other suggestions, I had originally written my query the way you suggested (only I used the column names). But when I saw it wasn't working, I tried with String.format(). Thanks for the heads up about SQLi, though.

Comment: I had run out of charcters in my other comments, so I split it to two parts: 
I also know that storing the password in plain text isn't the best idea, I was planning to switch to the hash+salt combo later. But since we're on the topic of hashed passwords. I was thinking of implementing it [this way](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode). Do you think it's a good idea, or should I search for another method of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

First you replace the `%s` placeholders with actual username and password, then you try to call setParameter(), but it is not there. The parameters in the query start with colon. Here's the correct code:

```
String sqlCommand = "select u from User u where u.userName = :uname and u.password = :pass";
Query q = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(sqlCommand);
q.setParameter("uname", userName);
q.setParameter("pass", passWord);
```

Comment: Actually, those two lines were left in accidentally. I had written the query similar to your suggestion but it wasn't working, so I tried switching to String.format() and I forgot to delete those lines. My actual mistake was that instead of the User object's fields' names, I wrote the names I gave the columns in the annotations. Thank you for your help!